# Cannot allocate new instance of UIView subclass after deallocating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

I have an instance variable *TangramLevel(:UIView) *currentLevel;* in my viewController class, and I have an instance allocated at start (it's retainCount 1). I attached it to the view *[self.view addSubview:currentLevel];* (retainCount 2).

When the level finishes, it notifies the controller, so controller removes it from the view *[currentLevel removeFromSuperview];* (retainCount 1), and release the allocated instance - *[currentLevel release];* -, to have it deallocated (retainCount 0 = invoke dealloc).

Then on the next line, **controller wants to allocate/addSubview a new level instance with another level data, but the application crashes** (EXEC BAD ACCESS).

If I don't release currentLevel after removeFromSuperview, the appliaction works, but I have an unused level instance left in memory then, which is also a problem (the main problem itself).

**Is there any bug in the method I wrote above?** Or the bug is elsewhere, maybe in the level class? I allocated some UIImageView in the level, but I release every allocated object in the levels dealloc method. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post more of the code (preferably in actual code blocks)? The basic sequence of events sounds OK, so I'd guess the problem is inside your level class. Possibly its dealloc method releases something that is still in use elsewhere?

Comment: Well, really the basic sequence of things sounds suspicious. See my answer below - an iVar's memory management (and access to the iVars) should be handled by its accessors and not manipulated elsewhere. I strongly suspect a design issue. The OP truly needs to post his/her code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post your code.

This is definitely a memory management issue. The question is "where is the problem created?" To answer that, we need to examine the following:

1. Your "currentLevel" iVar handling code (do you used synthesized properties, etc.). Post it.
2. How are you assigning the view to currentLevel?
3. Where are you releasing this, specifically?
4. How is your view's dealloc implemented (what do you release and how)?
5. Is there any other code that retains/releases this view or anything related to it?

The fact that you're calling release in your "I'm done with this level, let's swap in the next" code suggests an overall design issue. Make the memory management of each of a class's iVars the responsibility of its accessors and ONLY use the accessors to interact with it (even from within the class/instance). With synthesized properties, this makes it brain-dead-simple. That way you don't have to worry about where to retain/release iVars because it's always funneled through the accessors.

Comment: The actual code is quiet long, I wont post it all. I think I'm gonna shorten it as long as it produces the bug. It would be a pleasure, if you'd examine it. I use C-style array of CGPoints, could it be responsible for crash?

Comment: Re: CGPoints + C array, I don't know - you haven't posted your code yet. ;-)

Comment: Rethink of the whole design-pattern is something I really would appreciate. My previous question was just about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769430/looking-for-concept-for-managing-game-level-views-level-selection-views-prefere

Comment: Could you take a look on it? It was "self-answered", maybe I'm wrong.